# How to detect error with gem install rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to reinstall Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 13.10. I've succeeded in installing RVM and Ruby and I've finished configuring the PATH. My problem is I cannot get past the gem install rails part. Here is what I've gotten so far:

$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError)
    no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/atomic-1.0.2.gemspec.rz)

I am not sure but from what I've read, the problem seems to lie in my internet connection. I haven't edited anything in my network configuration though. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

seems you cannot connect to the rubygems website, can you make sure the network is working well? otherwise, you can use `source 'http://ruby.taobao.org/'` instead(this is a open ruby gems repo hosted in China, you can use it as a test).

Comment: Still not working even with the added source. I'm sure that my network is working well. Same output except that another line appears:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from http://ruby.taobao.org/ - no such     name (http://ruby.taobao.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.0.2.gemspec.rz)

Comment: @joseminicario you should execute `bundle install` under your rails root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like you.
I was using `sudo gem install rails` and sudo was using a different RVM version (`gem install rails` without sudo did the trick).
In short, your system probably uses the 'base' Ruby, not the RVM ruby.
Have you checked `which gem` and verified it's the same path like `which ruby`?